# How to explain the query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a complex query in elasticsearch. it's slow. I want to optimize it.
but i can't know how to work .
how to explain the query , like Sql explain.

i see elastichsearch _valite/query?explain . it can explain score.
but I need to view detailed execution plan.

```
{
  "post_filter": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "base.sysCode": "2801"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "base.status": [
                    12,
                    0
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "fields": [
    "base.sysCode",
    "base.orderNo"
  ]
}
```

result

```
{
"valid": true,
"_shards": {
"total": 1,
"successful": 1,
"failed": 0
},
"explanations": [
{
"index": "odi_bus_betad_2013",
"valid": true,
"explanation": "ConstantScore(*:*)"
}
]
}
```

Comment: Is this your full query, If not could you post the full query?

Comment: For performance reasons use only a [_post_filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_post_filter.html) if you need to differentiate search results and aggregations.

Answer (score 58):

**Explain API**

Computes a score explanation for a query and a specific document. This can give useful feedback whether a document matches or didn’t match a specific query.

Add `"explain": true`

```
GET /_search
{
    "explain": true,
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

[Explain Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html)

**Profile API**

Provides detailed timing information about the execution of individual components in a search request. It gives the user insight into how search requests are executed at a low level so that the user can understand why certain requests are slow, and take steps to improve them.

Add `"profile": true`

```
GET /_search
{
  "profile": true,
  "query" : {
    "match" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
  }
}
```

[Profile Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-profile.html)

Comment: Why is this not the selected answer?

Comment: I had to remove the `?explain` after `_search` and it started working. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Stick the profile keyword into your query if you're running a recent version:

```
GET binary/_search
{
   "profile": true,
    "query": {
     ...
        }
    }
}
```

If you had X-Pack, you could use the GUI based profiler to see where it's sluggish. Sadly not available in the open-source version, but it's just a prettier version of the output from the above - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/5.6/xpack-profiler.html

You might be able to do a 30 day trial, or if you are lucky, maybe you already have the X-Pack licence.

Answer (score 2):

You did everything right. You ran your query with `explain` and Elasticsearch did show you the detailed execution plan, under `explanations`.

However, the detailed execution plan here apparently has no details at all; this is because you actually did not run a query at all. You ran just a `post_filter` (the very first keyword in your example.)

Because you didn't specify a query at all, Elasticsearch matches every single document in your index and applies a constant score to all of them. This is why, under `explanations`, you see: `"explanation": "ConstantScore(*:*)"`

Because every single document in your index was matched, the `post_filter` you specified is applied against each one of them. This in itself is already slow; to make it even worse, post filters are never cached. (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_post_filter.html) So `explain` would never tell you any filter or cache information for your example, even if it could.

So, to answer your question: `explain` already returned the best detailed execution plan Elasticsearch could offer given your specific example. You can try a regular `filter` instead of a `post_filter` to give Elasticsearch a chance to build caches and increase performance.

Answer (score 1):

The usage for the Explain API is [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-explain.html)

> The explain api computes a score explanation for a query and a
>   specific document. This can give useful feedback whether a document
>   matches or didn’t match a specific query.

Comment: I don't need to score calculation. i need a filter and cache info.

Comment: Ah I see, it may be out of the scope of my knowledge. [Indices Stats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html) could provide some of the information you are looking for.

Comment: is there any `explain` feature that computes the score of all fetched documents? I mean not just one by one explanation?